# Joomla and "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 78 bytes)"

Tags: memory, joomla

I have site on Joomla, which was installed from another server : I copied all files, transfered their to var/www and discovered. After this I add MySQL-dump from another server to new MySQL database. That's OK - I can enter to admin-panel and even see the my materials that I need.

But when I try to see the site - I found 500 Error, that was misundstanding for me. Then I added

```
ini_set('display_errors','On'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to index.php to check what's happenng with my site and was shocked that :
**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 78 bytes) in /var/www/libraries/joomla/filter/filterinput.php on line 530**

that's very strange becouse of the RAM of my VPS is more than enougph. In the start of index.php I have code:

```
<?php ini_set("memory_limit", "128M"); ?>
```

Does somebody know how to fix such trouble?

Thanks.

Comment: 128Mb is way more than any Joomla installation should take, unless you are testing your memory the size shouldn't exceed 10Mb even with complex setups.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is saying that it's trying to allocate 78 bytes more memory than allowed, the allowed amount is **1342217728 bytes** which is **128M**.

So you've exhausted the memory allowed - you therefore need to increase the allowed allowed allocation.